# How to parse string into words and punctuation marks using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string test="hello how are you all doing, I hope that it's good! and fine. Looking forward to see you.

I am trying to parse the string into words and punctuation marks using javascript. I am able to separate words but then punctuation marks disappear using the regex

var result= test.match(/\b(\w|')+\b/g);

So my expected output is

```
hello
how 
are 
you
all
doing
,
I
hope
that
it's
good
!
and 
fine
.
Looking
forward
to
see
you
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Simple approach

This first approach if you, and javascript's definition of "word" match.  A more customizable approach is below.

Try `test.split(/\s*\b\s*/)`.  It splits on word boundaries (`\b`) and eats whitespace.

```
"hello how are you all doing, I hope that it's good! and fine. Looking forward to see you."
    .split(/\s*\b\s*/);
// Returns:
["hello",
"how",
"are",
"you",
"all",
"doing",
",",
"I",
"hope",
"that",
"it",
"'",
"s",
"good",
"!",
"and",
"fine",
".",
"Looking",
"forward",
"to",
"see",
"you",
"."]
```

### How it works.

```
var test = "This is. A test?"; // Test string.

// First consider splitting on word boundaries (\b).
test.split(/\b/); //=> ["This"," ","is",". ","A"," ","test","?"]
// This almost works but there is some unwanted whitespace.

// So we change the split regex to gobble the whitespace using \s*
test.split(/\s*\b\s*/) //=> ["This","is",".","A","test","?"]
// Now the whitespace is included in the separator
// and not included in the result.
```

## More involved solution.

If you want words like "isn`t" and "one-thousand" to be treated as a single word while javascript regex considers them to be two you will need to create your own definition of a word.

```
test.match(/[\w-']+|[^\w\s]+/g) //=> ["This","is",".","A","test","?"]
```

### How it works

This matches the actual words an punctuation characters separately using an alternation.  The first half of the regex `[\w-']+` matches whatever you consider to be a word, and the second half `[^\w\s]+` matches whatever you consider punctuation.  In this example I just used whatever isn't a word or whitespace.  I also but a `+` on the end so that multi-character punctuation (such as ?! which is properly written ‽) is treated as a single character, if you don't want that remove the `+`.

Comment: hey it worked but can you explain what exactly /\s*\b\s*/ it does ?

Comment: Check the [character classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters).  You could try something like `/[^\w\s]/` where you are saying anything that is not a word and not a space.  It's not perfect but you can add more exceptions to it.  Or just list everything you consider punctuation `/[!@#$%^&*(),.;:'"/?\\]/`.

Comment: Hey i got all of it thanks. Just one last thing i have word isn't and it is broken into is ' and t  I dont want that i want it to be one complete word. ist't

Comment: I added a second approach that can use a custom definition of "word".

Comment: How would you modify this to keep all the whitespace?

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
[,.!?;:]|\b[a-z']+\b
```

See the matches in [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/40).

For instance, in JavaScript:

```
resultArray = yourString.match(/[,.!?;:]|\b[a-z']+\b/ig);
```

**Explanation**

- The character class `[,.!?;:]` matches one character from inside the brackets
- OR (alternation `|`)
- `\b` match a word boundary
- `[a-z']+` one or more letters or apostrophes
- `\b` word boundary

Comment: FYI: Added demo and explanation. :)

Comment: hey bro it seperates co-education as two seperate words can i have it as one word ?