# Javascript: find word in string

Tags: javascript, substring, cpu-word

Does Javascript have a built-in function to see if a word is present in a string? I'm not looking for something like `indexOf()`, but rather:

```
find_word('test', 'this is a test.') -> true
find_word('test', 'this is a test') -> true
find_word('test', 'I am testing this out') -> false
find_word('test', 'test this out please') -> true
find_word('test', 'attest to that if you would') -> false
```

Essentially, I'd like to know if my word appears, but not as part of another word. It wouldn't be too hard to implement manually, but I figured I'd ask to see if there's already a built-in function like this, since it seems like it'd be something that comes up a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if one string contains another substring in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher did you read the question?

Comment: Actually, yes, I see the one spot where it's false, because of it being 'testing', and thus, that's the difference. But your question reads like *"I don't like the syntax of indexOf(), what can I use instead"* instead of actually explaining that indexOf() doesn't do what I want because ... explanation

Comment: @Mala Yes I did.  The linked answer discusses the regex, though briefly.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher The person asking the question is asking a fundamentally different question, and scanning down the answers I don't see any that would answer the question above. My apologies if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `split` and `some`:

```
function findWord(word, str) {
  return str.split(' ').some(function(w){return w === word})
}
```

Or use a regex with word boundaries:

```
function findWord(word, str) {
  return RegExp('\\b'+ word +'\\b').test(str)
}
```

Comment: The former wouldn't handle punctuation properly, but the latter looks like it'd be what I need. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose to make the first one work, one could use `.split(/\s*\b\s*/)` as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718348/how-to-parse-string-into-words-and-punctuation-marks-using-javascript. Didn't know about the .some() function, so thanks for teaching me about that too :)

Comment: The two functions aren't equivalent. `findWord('test', 'test-team')` will return *false* in the first case and *true* in the second. The first should split on `\b` or the second use `' '`. The second is likely very much faster for big strings.

Answer (score 5):

The JavaScript [`includes()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) method determines whether a string contains the characters of a specified string. This method returns true if the string contains the characters, and false if not.

Syntax:

```js
string.includes(searchvalue, start)
```

Parameter values:

```
Parameter      Description
searchvalue    Required. The string to search for
start          Optional. Default 0. At which position to start the search
```

Example:

```js
const sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';
const word = 'fox';
console.log(`The word "${word}" ${sentence.includes(word) ? 'is' : 'is not'} in the sentence`);
```

Answer (score -1):

Moderns browsers have the [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), which determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

Here's an example:

```js
const ShoppingList = ["Milk", "Butter", "Sugar"];

console.log(`Milk ${ShoppingList.includes("Milk") ? "is" : "is not"} in the shopping list.`);

console.log(`Eggs ${ShoppingList.includes("Eggs") ? "is" : "is not"} in the shopping list.`)
```

Comment: Perhaps rephrase your answer without typos.

Comment: Include a link to the [`includes`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) method, an example of usage